# React usage with RTK Query can cause memory leak on unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

When using RTK Query within a React component, it's very possible for a memory leak / no-op error to be thrown if the component is unmounted before the query completes.

For example, if you use `isError` or `isSuccess` RTK will attempt to set these even if the component is unmounted.

Previously I would manually check that the fetch was not aborted and only set state if needed.  I'm unsure how to handle this with RTK Query where the state is handled automatically.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to deal with it, or RTK Query is able to handle this in some way that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

This error message can be ignored at this point, because it's actually already going away in React 18:

https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82

> To sum up, we're removing this warning. The case for which it's relevant (subscriptions) is not very common in the product code, and is typically encapsulated in custom Hooks and libraries. The case that most product developers encounter is the one where this warning is not only useless/misleading, but also pushes developers to worse solutions while trying to suppress the warning. Hopefully, this change will reduce the confusion, and let you remove a bunch of isMounted checks from your code.

Comment: Thank you!  I had no idea this was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your interpretation or are you actually getting an error message here? In RTK-Query, that data will be persisted to the store (in case you navigate back) but will be removed after 60 seconds if no component using it mounts. A memory leak is pretty much impossible, it's just not bound to the individual component because it builds on Redux.

Comment: It's happening.
I tested it by running a query on a button click which took at least 5 seconds to run.  I immediately navigated away from the page.  After 5 seconds the `unmounted component` error is displayed in the console.  Perhaps I have something configured incorrectly, however I don't think I do and my use-cases is fairly basic.

Comment: Could you please verify is this still happens with the latest v1.7 beta and if that is the case please open an issue with a reproduction?

Comment: Will do!  I set this lil test up solely to check if this was an issue with RTK as I had the same thoughts as you.